# Datakeys count returning 0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, page-lifecycle

I created a master page (my template page) and i place a gridview on it. Now I will create mutiple pages (aspx) that will use this master page. Instead of doing all the setup for these aspx pages, all I have to do is configure a datasource. When the aspx loads it connects the datasource to the gridview (on the master page) and it loads. Now I would like to manipulate data inside the gridview but my datakeys count is returning 0. I can access values via `gv.Rows(dr.RowIndex).Cells(5)` for example. But I want to do it via the data keys. My code is below, any help is appreciated. thanks.

```
Public Sub ConnectDataSource()
    Dim mpContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
    Dim gv As GridView
    mpContentPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("GridViewPlaceHolder"), ContentPlaceHolder)
    If Not mpContentPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then
        gv = CType(mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView)
        If Not gv Is Nothing Then
            Dim es As EntityDataSource = EntityDataSource1
            gv.DataSource = es
            gv.DataBind()
            Debug.WriteLine("datakey count  " + gv.DataKeys().Count.ToString())
            ' gv.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Text = "sdfds" // to change header text for each column.
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PaymentRules_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim toolbarPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
    Dim btn As ImageButton
    toolbarPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("ToolBarPlaceHolder"), ContentPlaceHolder)
    If Not toolbarPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then
        btn = DirectCast(toolbarPlaceHolder.FindControl("ImageButton2"), ImageButton)
        If Not btn Is Nothing Then
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ImageButton2_Click
        End If
    End If
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        ConnectDataSource()
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("ImageButton2_Click")
    Dim maList As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim mContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
    Dim gv As GridView
    mContentPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("GridViewPlaceHolder"), ContentPlaceHolder)
    If Not mContentPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then
        gv = CType(mContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView)
        If Not gv Is Nothing Then
            For Each dr As GridViewRow In gv.Rows
                If ((TryCast(dr.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)).Checked = True) Then
                    'Debug.WriteLine(dr.RowIndex.ToString())
                    'Dim id As Integer = gv.DataKeys(dr.RowIndex).Value
                    'maList.Add(id)
                    Debug.WriteLine("row index " + gv.Rows(dr.RowIndex).Cells(5).Text)
                    Debug.WriteLine("datakey count  " + gv.DataKeys().Count.ToString())
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

EDITED - Master Page Code

---

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="JSPSite.master.vb" Inherits="SSPayroll.JSPSite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Styles/Style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">

            <h1>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/GSCV1.01 - Copy.png" 
                    Height="73px" style="margin-top: 20px" Width="428px" />
            </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="User: " Font-Names="Cambria"></asp:Label><span class="bold">
                            <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" Font-Names="Cambria" />
                        </span> [
                        <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect"
                            LogoutPageUrl="~/" Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#D9D5D5" Font-Bold="True" LogoutText="Sign Out" />
                        ]
                                            <div>

                </div>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>   
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Date/Time" Font-Names="Cambria" 
                        Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333"></asp:Label>            
             </div>

            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" BackColor="#FFFBD6" 
                    DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
                    ForeColor="#990000" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Enabled="True">
                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                    <Items>
                                            <asp:MenuItem  Text="Menu1" Value="Tools">
                                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/JSPayroll/Payment_Rules/PaymentRules.aspx" Text="Payment Rules" Value="Payment Rules"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>

                    </Items>
                    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>  
        </div> 
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ToolBarPlaceHolder" runat="server" >
           <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
              <div>
                <hr />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/Home.png" Width="48px" ToolTip="Home" CssClass="morph" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/Add.png" ToolTip="Add Record" CssClass="morph" Width="48px"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/Edit E.png" ToolTip="Edit Record" CssClass="morph" Width="48px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/ViewDetails.png" ToolTip="View Record Details" CssClass="morph" Width="48px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/Delete.png" ToolTip="Delete Record" CssClass="morph" Width="48px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton6" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/Approved.png" ToolTip="Approve Record" CssClass="morph" Width="48px"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton7" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/Denied.png" ToolTip="Unapprove Record" CssClass="morph" Width="48px"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton8" runat="server" Height="48px" ImageUrl="~/IconsPack/Update.png" ToolTip="Refresh Table" CssClass="morph" Width="48px"/>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 

        <%--<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="GridViewPlaceHolder" runat="server">--%>
            <div class="EU_TableScroll" id="showData" style="display: block">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="EU_DataTable" EmptyDataText="No Data Available.">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />  
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        <%--</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>--%>
        <div class="main">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put ImageButtons and GridView and EntityDataSource out of ContentPlaceHolde.
You do not neet use FindControl but to CheckBox.
In GridView1 set **DataKeyNames** property to your key.

Comment: can you expand on this .. why must i do this?

Comment: I took it out and still returns 0!

Comment: Thanks but i dont think you understand my question. With the code you just added.. I have that and I said its working. I want to use datakeys on the gridview instead..

Comment: you do not need to use FindControl to use GridView and you need use FindControl to work with CheckBox only.

Comment: Anyway i can set this in the code behind rather than directly on the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the DataKeyNames property on the Gridview .aspx side. Check below sample code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx).  If you set DataKeyNames property then only I think you might be able to access the DataKeys property in the code behind.

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        emptydatatext="No data available." 
        autogenerateselectbutton="true"    
        datakeynames="CustomerID"
        onselectedindexchanged="CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
        runat="server">

      </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Thank you .. this is what was missing.

Comment: anyway i can set this in the code behind rather than directly on the gridview?